# reduce intersect troubleshooting

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have a list of data frames called csv3 where each data frame has two columns 'XY_ID' and 'CellID'. 
I am trying to find the common elements (XY_ID) to all 9 data frames in the list. For some reason this is not working anymore but I know it should be.
What am I missing ?

```
str(csv3)
List of 9
 $ :'data.frame':   41999 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41337 levels "100.078:217.09",..: 8416 8310 7651 8069 8253 7924 6840 6918 7569 6747 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41999] 0 0 7 0 0 7 8 8 7 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42034 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41381 levels "100.1375:226.319",..: 8226 7565 7983 8169 7838 6761 6840 7484 6666 7246 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42034] 0 7 7 0 7 8 8 7 8 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42133 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41471 levels "100.1375:226.319",..: 8004 8189 7859 6780 6859 7509 6686 7267 7080 7549 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42133] 0 0 7 8 8 7 8 7 8 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41999 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41346 levels "100.1375:226.319",..: 8342 7980 8238 7456 7577 7996 8181 7004 7848 6773 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41999] 0 0 0 7 7 7 7 8 7 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41959 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ NA.   : logi [1:41959] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41959] 0 0 7 0 0 7 7 8 8 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42055 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41394 levels "100.137:226.319",..: 8416 7749 8170 8359 8025 7665 6835 7422 7235 7706 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42055] 0 7 0 0 0 7 8 7 7 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41865 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41212 levels "100.078:217.09",..: 8498 8130 7876 8391 6614 7595 7721 8146 8333 7136 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41865] 0 0 7 0 8 7 7 7 0 8 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   42078 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41418 levels "100.137:226.319",..: 8070 8258 7924 6841 7571 6748 7331 7144 7611 7836 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:42078] 0 0 7 8 7 8 7 8 7 7 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   41912 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 41255 levels "100.078:217.09",..: 8420 8056 7803 8315 6547 7529 7650 8072 8257 7069 ...
  ..$ CellID: int [1:41912] 0 0 7 0 8 7 7 7 7 8 ...


> head(csv3[[1]])
            XY_ID CellID
1 193.722:175.733      0
2 192.895:176.727      0
3 187.065:178.285      7
4 190.754:178.186      0
5 192.296:178.648      0
6 189.421:179.012      7

lapply(csv3, '[[', 'XY_ID')
WORKING!

Reduce(intersect,lapply(csv3, '[[', 'XY_ID'))
character(0)
```

Comment: Maybe it's a factors thing, try converting to character: `Reduce(function(x, y) intersect(as.character(x), as.character(y)), lapply(csv3, '[[', 'XY_ID'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a weird `NA` column in your fifth data frame.

```
Reduce(intersect,lapply(csv3, '[[', 'XY_ID'))  ## working
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
```

Now let's make a copy and mimic this `NA` column

```
csv4 <- csv3

csv4[[3]][1] <- NA
names(csv4[[3]])[1] <- "NA."

str(csv4)
# List of 3
# $ :'data.frame':  15 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 15 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# ..$ CellID: int [1:15] 1 5 1 9 4 2 1 8 7 4 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  15 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ XY_ID : Factor w/ 15 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# ..$ CellID: int [1:15] 9 9 4 5 5 4 2 8 3 1 ...
# $ :'data.frame':  15 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ NA.   : logi [1:15] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
# ..$ CellID: int [1:15] 6 2 5 4 2 8 2 3 8 7 ...
```

...and try again.

```
lapply(csv4, '[[', 'XY_ID')  ## working
# [[1]]
# [1] a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
# Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
# Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t
# 
# [[3]]
# NULL

Reduce(intersect,lapply(csv4, '[[', 'XY_ID'))  ## NOT working
# NULL
```

*Conclusion:* You probably should examine where that `NA` column comes from.

---

*Data:*

```
csv3 <- list(structure(list(XY_ID = structure(1:15, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"
), class = "factor"), CellID = c(1L, 5L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
8L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L)), structure(list(XY_ID = structure(1:15, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o"), class = "factor"), CellID = c(9L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
8L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L)), structure(list(XY_ID = structure(1:15, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o"), class = "factor"), CellID = c(6L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 
3L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem, I realised by doing ```lapply(csv, dim)``` that my original list (before any change) had some empty columns that appeared like NA for the rest of the analysis and caused lots of problems. 
Thanks a lot for the help and the catch!